# Don't understand actionmenu

Tags: gui-construction

This works fine to get domain from a dropdown, but I wrote it     years ago, and although I thought I understood it, I clearly don't because I can't get rid of pure functions to make it work at all. I can't find any documentation about loading the action box either, although the above loads it fine without being in the action menu brackets weirdly. Have tried every permutation. Yes, it works but why can't it work when $surface stands in for #, or even #1&/@$surface and take out &'s elsewhere??

Thanks

````
     {{ {u ,                               v,                  
    3 - u^2 - v^2},     {-2, 2}, {-2, 2},      {-2, 2}, {-2, 
    2},    {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 4},     {0.3, 0.34} },    
      { {u,                                v,                         
       u^2 - v^2},      {-1, 1}, {-1, 1} ,        {-1, 1}, {-1,     1} , {-1,
     1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 2},      {-0.3, -0.34} },
  { { 3 Cos[v] Cos[u], 3 Cos[v] Sin[u], 3 Sin[v]}, {0.0 , 2 Pi}, {0.0,
     Pi/2}, {-3 Pi, 3 Pi}, {0, Pi}    , {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {0, 
    4},    { 4.46, 0.780}    } ,
  {{u ,                               v,              
    1 +    .5 u + .5 v},     {-1, 1}, {-1, 1},      {-1, 1}, {-1, 
    1},    {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 2},     {0.01, 0.01} } }
 ;```   

 

   
   Manipulate[
     Dynamic[domainu],
     {{surface, $surface[[2, 1]]}, 
  ActionMenu[#1, (#1[[
     1]] :> ({surface, domainu, domainv, gdomainu, gdomainv, 
       rangex, rangey, rangez, startpt} = #1) & ) /@         $surface, 
    ImageSize -> {150, 40}] &}, {{domainu, $surface[[2, 2]]}, None}]```
 





This works fine to get domain from a dropdown, but I wrote it     years ago, and although I thought I understood it, I clearly don't because I can't get rid of pure functions to make it work at all. I can't find any documentation about loading the action box either, although the above loads it fine without being in the action menu brackets weirdly. Have tried every permutation. Yes, it works but why can't it work when $surface stands in for #, or even #1&/@$surface and take out &'s elsewhere??

Thanks
````

Comment: Manipulate[
 
 Dynamic[domainu],
 {{surface, $surface[[2, 1]]}, 
  ActionMenu[#1, (#1[[
         1]] :> ({surface, domainu, domainv, gdomainu, gdomainv, 
           rangex, rangey, rangez, startpt} = #1) & ) /@ $surface, 
    ImageSize -> {150, 40}] &}, {{domainu, $surface[[2, 2]]}, None}]

Comment: sorry just earning to use, forgive my errors in trying to get code onto site(tried latex), and commenting on my question to clarify!

Comment: We can directly post the Mathematica code cnclose by  ```  code   ```  or  using the code input frame.

Comment: using ``` doesn't help, big red warning asking to use ``` after copy paste and indenting. I'm not even smart enough to ask the question on stack exchange!